# Changing text attributes (font, size, etc) at the cursor level in a google doc using Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I would like know if and how it is possible to change text attributes such as font, size, etc. in Google Apps script at the cursor's level. The script is bound to a Google doc file. For example, after running the script, the text font will change for anything written after that point while leaving the text written before unchanged. This is to mimic the way built-in styles or font menus behave in Google docs.

Here is what I came up with so far. It seems to change the text font globally in the document instead of applying the changes only to the text written after running the code. Any suggestions?

```
var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();

if(cursor){ 
var element4 = cursor.getElement()
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody()
if (element4.editAsText) {
   body.editAsText().setFontFamily(DocumentApp.FontFamily.CALIBRI);
}
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you left this post unanswered?  Did you try the code below.?

Answer (score 1):

The code below changes the `FontFamily` for the paragraph in which you select a text... it keeps the same style for all what is coming after and preserves everything before.

If you want to go deeper in precision you'll have to play with offsets and work at text level inside the paragraph but I thought this version could be sufficient.

```
function setStyle() {
var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
  if (!selection) {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot find a selection in the document.');
    return;
  }
  var selectedElements = selection.getSelectedElements();
  var element = selectedElements[0].getElement().getParent(); 
  element.setFontFamily(DocumentApp.FontFamily.CONSOLAS);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The DocumentApp.FontFamily enumeration is now deprecated. You should use string names, like "Consolas" (case sensitive!), instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can visit the setAttributes section of the DocumentApp Reference found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#setAttributes(Object))